# How to return array instead of collection using Fractal Transformers in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, rest, thephpleague, thephpleague-fractal

I am using Fractal Transformers in one of the Laravel based REST API project. I have a `$defaultInclude` and thus have a function in the Transformer class(`ReleaseTransformer`) to process the includes. It is as follows :

```
public function includeDetails($item)
{
    $details = $item->details;

     return $details
        ? $this->collection($details, new DetailsTransformer())
        : $this->null();
}
```

and in `DetailsTranformer` class I have

```
public function transform($item)
{
    return [$item->detail];
}
```

I am getting the correct data here, but the response is as follows :

```
"details": {
     "data": [
          [
              "DETAIL-ID-1"
          ],
          [
              "DETAIL-ID-2"
          ],
          [
              "DETAIL-ID-3"
          ],
      ]
  }
```

I would like to get the response as an array like the following:

```
"details":["DETAIL-ID-1", "DETAIL-ID-2", "DETAIL-ID-3"]
```

I am using the extension `spatie/laravel-fractal` and the response is obtained by using :

```
fractal($release, new ReleaseTransformer())->toArray();
```

How can I modify the code as it will return this array ?

Comment: Why not just return `return $item->detail;` instead?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for this. We can use the `flatten()` method of Laravel collections and it will make the returned array single dimensional. So the code will be as follows :

```
$data = fractal($release, new ReleaseTransformer())->toArray();

$dataAsArray = collecet($data)->flatten()->all();
```

PS: I am not sure it is a correct to use transformers for the scenario I have mentioned, but just putting the answer if someone needs it.